# RecyclerView is not keeping state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm using an Recycler View to load a list of items on a fragment. This fragment can be replaced using a `Bottom Bar Navigation`.

When I change the fragment, and then come back to this fragment, the Recycler View scroll is maintained, as expected; this is the code on `onCreteView()` method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View cl = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contents, container, false);

    contentList = (RecyclerView) cl.findViewById(R.id.contentList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    contentList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    contentList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    contentList.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean contentsLoaded = sharedPref.getBoolean("contentsLoaded", false);

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) cl.findViewById(R.id.contents_swipe);

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            content_list.getContents().clear();
            loadContents(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        }
    });

    contentList.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new ChannelRecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), contentList ,new ChannelRecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Intent contentActivity = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ContentActivity.class );

                    Content content = (Content) view.getTag();

                    Channel channel = content_list.findChannelById(content.getChannelId());
                    Town town = content_list.findTownById(content.getTownId());
                    User author = content_list.findUserById(content.getAuthorId());

                    contentActivity.putExtra("id", content.getId());
                    contentActivity.putExtra("title", content.getTitle());
                    contentActivity.putExtra("lastEdit", new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").format(content.getLastEdit()));
                    contentActivity.putExtra("description", content.getDescription());

                    contentActivity.putExtra("channelName", channel.getName());
                    contentActivity.putExtra("channelPic", channel.getPicture());

                    contentActivity.putExtra("townName", town.getName());
                    contentActivity.putExtra("townPic", town.getPicture());

                    contentActivity.putExtra("authorName", author.getName());
                    contentActivity.putExtra("authorSurname", author.getSurname());

                    startActivity(contentActivity);
                }

                @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    // do whatever
                }
            })
    );

    if(contentsLoaded) {
        LoadFromCache();
        return cl;
    }

    loadContents(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("contentsLoaded", true);
    editor.apply();


    return cl;
}
```

Here, the important part is the `LoadFromCache()` call that retrieve items from database and reload RecyclerView.

The problem comes when I put this code on my `onResume()` method:

```
    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LoadFromCache();
}
```

Then, when I switch between fragments, the scroll is reset to top. I cannot understand why in the `onCreateView()` method is working fine, but not in my `onResume()` method, since it's the same call.

More info:

**LoadFromCache() function:**

```
public void LoadFromCache(Void...voids){
    new LoadContentsFromDatabase(contentList).execute();
}
```

**LoadContentsFromDatabase class:**

```
public class LoadContentsFromDatabase extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ContentList> {

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
RecyclerView contentList;

public LoadContentsFromDatabase(RecyclerView contentList) {
    this.contentList = contentList;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    //Perform pre-adding operation here.
}

@Override
protected ContentList doInBackground(Void...voids) {

    //Select data from DB
    List<Town> towns = db.townDao().getAll();
    List<Channel> channels = db.channelDao().getAll();
    List<User> users = db.userDao().getAll();
    List<Content> contents = db.contentDao().getAll();

    return new ContentList(new ArrayList(contents), new ArrayList(towns), new ArrayList(channels), new ArrayList(users), null);

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ContentList list) {
    super.onPostExecute(list);

    //To after addition operation here.

    contentAdapter = new ContentAdapter(list);
    contentList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    contentList.setAdapter(contentAdapter);
    contentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    ContentsFragment.content_list = list;

}
}
```

**EDIT: How I switch between fragments**

My home activity is in charge of manage fragments switch:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String userToken;
public static ContentParser contentParser = new ContentParser();
public static TownParser townParser = new TownParser();
public static ChannelParser channelParser = new ChannelParser();
public static QuestionParser questionParser = new QuestionParser();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    userToken = sharedPref.getString("token", null);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);

    View contentsButton = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.action_contents);
    contentsButton.performClick();

    final ContentsFragment contentsFragment = new ContentsFragment();
    final TownsFragment townsFragment = new TownsFragment();
    final ChannelsFragment channelsFragment = new ChannelsFragment();
    final QuestionsFragment questionsFragment = new QuestionsFragment();

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_towns:
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, townsFragment).commit();
                            break;

                        case R.id.action_channels:
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, channelsFragment).commit();
                            break;

                        case R.id.action_contents:
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, contentsFragment).commit();
                            break;

                        case R.id.action_question:
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, questionsFragment).commit();
                            break;

                        case R.id.action_user:
                            break;

                    }

                    return true;
                }


            });

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, contentsFragment);
    transaction.commit();

}

}
```

Comment: How do you replace fragments using the bottom navigation? Can you post the fragment transaction code?

Comment: Hi @BenP. , I updated my question with the code you required for. Thank for your help.

Comment: You mentioned in the comments on my answer that you see `onCreateView()` being called each time, due to logging you have in place. I guess this means that the fragment's view has been destroyed, even if it's the same fragment instance. To verify that it's the same fragment instance, could you update your logging to include whether or not `savedInstanceState` is null inside `onCreateView()`, and let me know the answer?

Comment: Thanks for your interest!
I just check what you request, and `savedInstanceState` is `null` on my logging. This mean that my fragment is destroyed even being the same intance?

It's this the problem that cause that scroll is miss? And how can fix it?

Comment: More info: If I remove `LoadFromCache()` from on resume, `savedInstanceState` still being `null` ; BUT scroll it's maintained on this case.